# Stored procedure - Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, procedure

In process of a college project that requires a simple stored procedure :

> Create a stored procedure that takes a single parameter that accepts a Date. Data type of Date will be datetime. This store procedure should return all renter and property information for viewings that occurred on that date.

It will be submitted on SQL Server from college, but at the moment at home I'm training with MS Access 2010.

Table = `Property_For_Rent`:

```
Pno  \\( this is the property ID )
Address_1
Address_2
Address_3
```

Table = `Renter`

```
Rno \\( this is the renter ID )
Fname
Lname
```

Table = `Viewing`

```
Rno
Pno
Date
```

Researching found another fellow on here with similar conundrum ( easier to tweak, if anyone can shine where went wrong be great , thank you!

```
create procedure sp_orders_by_dates
    @startdate smalldatetime,
    @enddate smalldatetime
as
    select  
       OrderID,
       o.CustomerID,
       c.CompanyName as CustomerCompany,
       s.ShipperID,
       s.CompanyName as ShipperCompany,
       ShippedDate
    from    
       Orders o 
    join 
       Customers c on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
    join 
       Shippers s on s.ShipperID = o.ShipperID
    where 
       @startdate = ShippedDate,
       @enddate = ShippedDate
    order by 
       ShippedDate
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  +1 for actually admitting its a college project, and showing what you have so far.

Comment: So, what exactly is the question?

Comment: Dwonload and install sql server express edition. Don't use access to learn sql server.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks guys, the questions is writing the code to show the details of renters and the properties on specific date ( in the viewing table)

Comment: Your columns `ShippedDate` in the table cannot possibly be equal to both the `@startDate` and the `@enddate` at the same time - which seems to be what you have in your `WHERE` clause - what do you **really** want to check for??

Comment: @marc_s thanks for edditing. i tried the way of using start and end date and putting in just one date . i need the coed to show results from only *one specific* date

Comment: if it helps all the entires are withing this date range : Date
05/03/2015
20/03/2015
03/03/2015
01/03/2015
23/03/2015
25/03/2015
28/03/2015
13/03/2015
22/03/2015
11/03/2015

Comment: So it probably should be `WHERE ShippedDate = @StartDate OR ShippedDate = @EndDate` ....

Comment: testing now will chat you with progress, not to strain your attention! thanks guys!

Comment: It should only be taking one parameter, right?  So get rid of @EndDate and just limit by `viewing.date = @StartDate`

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it.
The tables you described are not even mentioned on the stored procedure.
How do you expect it to work?

You should use `INNER JOIN` on all 3 tables, and compare the `Date` column on table `Viewing` to your `@Date` variable in the `WHERE` clause.
Basically, it should look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON(T1.JoinColumn = T2.JoinColumn)
INNER JOIN Table3 T3 ON(T2.OtherJoinColumn = T3.JoinColumn)
WHERE Table3.ConditionColumn = @Date
```

Now all you have to do is figure out how to fit your tables and columns into that sql statement instead of my mockups.
Good luck.

Comment: I don't think they wrote the code they included - I think it was copied from someone else's similar question and they're asking us to modify it for their situation.

Comment: @aphrael maybe, but unless this is a project on how to get other people to do your homework, my answer will be more beneficial to the OP than just giving him the full and tested solution. To the best of my knowledge, programming is learned using one's fingers.

Comment: Totally agree.  Just commenting on the first paragraph of your answer.

Comment: Hey guys , thank you all for helping out fellow student ! I have tried his method , end result : ALTER PROCEDURE Renter_Property_Info_by_Date
@Date datetime
SELECT *
FROM Renter T1
INNER JOIN Viewing T2 ON(T1.Rno = T2.Rno)
INNER JOIN Property_for_Rent T3 ON(T2.Pno = T3.Pno)
WHERE Viewing.Pno = Date
GO

Comment: and even without the "Go" still errors at :  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'. By looking at that code Zohar it doesnt still provide whats needed as you see above i have 3 tables to use Property_For_Rent :Pno ( This is the id ) , Renter : Rno (renters id) , Fname, Lname an Viewing : Pno , Rno , Date , Comment. If you could help with the above code that link pno to rno and  comments using the stored DATE procedure . Thank you very much i absolutely greatly appreciate it

Comment: All sorted guys!! Aprael and Zohar Peled Yous are amazing!

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark the answer as accepted or write your final solution and accept it so that people will know the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

SQL implementations aren't the same.  They don't all use *exactly* the same syntax, and they don't all implement *exactly* the same things.  For instance, MS-Access (so far as I know) doesn't provide stored-procs at all.  (But it does know how to issue queries and DML-commands, to appropriate servers that *do.*)

Such as, for instance, "SQL Server!"  :-)  Microsoft *does* provide, free of charge, "SQL Server Express" which *is* (most of ...) SQL Server, designed for use on one machine.  Using this tool, you should be able to replicate virtually the same environment that you expect to be using in the lab.  And of course, MS-Access is a very fine tool to use to, well, "access" what you've done.

Comment: While true, this is not answering the question in any way. Also, I've commented on the question on this exact same issue 40 minutes before you wrote this post.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with a datetime datatype, you have to factor in the time of day.

```
 where shippedDate >= @dateParameter
 and shippedDate < DateAdd(day, 1, @dateParameter)
```

Get used to this approach when working with datatypes that include both a date and a time.